# Isolation and concurrence in Django

Tags: django-rest-framework, postgresql-9.5, isolation-level

I am using DjangoREST with PostgreSQL. I have these two models:
author/models.py:

```
class Author(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
     allsize =  models.FloatField(default=0)
```

and in files/models.py:

```
class File(models.Model):
     author =  models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
     size = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

If I upload multiple files having the same size (from the front end), in order to update the allsize field (which is sum of the all uploaded files) of the author, DjangoREST didn't update correctly the values maybe according to the concurrency (they have same size), despite I am doing a raw sql transaction:

```
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("BEGIN; set transaction isolation level read committed;"
                        "update author_author set allsize = allsize + %s where author_id = %s;",
                               [validated_data.get('size', 0), validated_data.get('author', 0)])
        cursor.execute("COMMIT;")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my SQL transaction works, I had a mistake in my code.

Answer (score 0):

`allsize` field is actually a duplication of data. The information is already present in your database (the sum of all the `File.size` related to this user).

If you want to get this information for a given `Author`, you could use :

```
class Author(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

     def all_size(self):
        return self.aggregate(all_size=Sum('files__size')).all_size
```

This way, you have no data duplication, and an easy way to get your **aggregate**

More resources in [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/)

Comment: Yes, it works, but it is not heavy that every time the user is connected to do this aggregation?

Comment: It is a DB-level aggregation. Your database is made for that, except if we talk about hundred of millions of records ! Compared to the pain to maintain two several sources of truth, and properly update each one for any change, the tradeoff is OK. If you want to improve performance, you can look at 'select_related()' method